# Combine two recursions into one tail-recursion code

Tags: racket, tail-recursion

I'm trying to define the function longestString that consumes a list (may
contain elements of any type) and returns the longest str

I have build two function to do so,
the first one takes a list of any type and outputs a list of only strings
the second takes a list of strings and outputs the longest string.
Now the problem I'm having is on how to combine these two functions to work together.
Any help would be appreciated

first function:

```
( : sublist-numbers  : (Listof Any) -> (Listof String))
  (define (sublist-numbers l )
  ( : sublist-numbers-helper  : (Listof Any) (Listof String)-> (Listof String))
  (define (sublist-numbers-helper l r)
  (cond ((null? l) r)
        ((string? (first l)) (sublist-numbers-helper (rest l) (cons (first l) r )))
        (else (sublist-numbers-helper (rest l) r))))
 (sublist-numbers-helper l '()))

second function:
( : maxOf : (Listof String) -> String)
   (define (maxOf l)
        (cond
            ;((null? list) (error "empty list") )
            ((null? (rest l)) (first l))
            (else (cond
                    ((> (string-length(first l)) (string-length(maxOf (rest l)))) (first l))
                    (else (maxOf (rest l))))))))
```

The output should be something like this:

(test (longestString '(34 uuu 90)) => false)
   (test (longestString '(uu 56 oooo "r" "rRR" "TTT")) => "rRR")

Comment: `(maxOf (sublist-numbers l))`? You do the same many times in your code. Eg `(string? (first l))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in your `maxOf` procedure, the empty-list case also needs to be considered:

```
(define (maxOf l)
  (cond ((null? l) "") ; a string type is required
        ((null? (rest l))
         (first l))
        ((> (string-length (first l)) (string-length (maxOf (rest l))))
         (first l))
        (else (maxOf (rest l)))))
```

After fixing that, `longestString` is trivial to implement: you just need to compose together `maxOf` and `sublist-numbers`, and to handle the case when no maximum element was found:

```
(define (longestString l)
  (let ((result (maxOf (sublist-numbers l))))
    (if (string=? result "")
        false
        result)))
```

It works as expected:

```
(longestString '(34 uuu 90))
=> #f
(longestString '(uu 56 oooo "r" "rRR" "TTT"))
=> "rRR"
```

Comment: First thanks a lot, there is one think I don't really understand and would be happy if you could explain, the maxOf function is defined as ( : maxOf : (Listof String) -> String), so it must return a string, how can I make it return either boolean or string(like in the fixed code you provided)? I'm asking beacuse I'm getting the error:Type Checker: type mismatch
  expected: String
  given: False in: #f

Comment: You're right, I updated my answer so `maxOf` always returns a `string`